# How do I access private member variables with public member functions (derived class)?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, derived-class

I need to get access of the base class private member variables using public member functions from the derived class. That means, I can call it anytime in a public member function from the derived class and change it anytime.

For example:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    int a = 19;
    public:
    int getA() // Function to get A
    {
        return a;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    void getAatB() // How do I get a variable at parent class (A)?
    {
        cout<<getA();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B a;
    a.getAatB();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to get access to variable a. How do I do this without changing `private` to `protected` or `public` at class A?

Comment: _I need to get access of the base class private member variables using public member functions from the derived class._ This is prohibited by design / by intention. (That's the actual intention to make a member variable `private` - to hide it from access outside of the class.) You have to add the public member function to the base class.

Comment: I do not understand the question. You are already calling `getA` to get the value of the private member `a` inside `getAatB`. Why do you think this wouldnt be ok? And why not `protected` ?

Comment: your code is accessing the private member in the derived class and works as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/fzG5r5GzP. It is unclear what the issue is

Comment: That would make `private` completely pointless. I believe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you feel that you need this?

Comment: Best approach: design code in such way that such access is not needed. Your current code is ok. Why do you think you need such access?

Comment: @MarekR It is just for example.

Comment: The solution is you change `private` to `protected` or `public` at class A.

Comment: @user253751 If not? What will be the solution?

Comment: @Recursion112 do what Mohamadreza said, or else, just don't.

Comment: @Recursion112 and I provided general rule, so "just an example" doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

the easy way of doing that is adding `friend class B;` to class A , so class B can access class A's attributes and you aren't going to need change private to protected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the descendants of `A` having a access to `getA()` member function, there is a special keyword `protected` in c++. The purpose of `protected`, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/protected-cpp?view=msvc-170) is.

> Class members declared as protected can be used only by the following:
>
> - Member functions of the class that originally declared these members.
> - Friends of the class that originally declared these members.
> - Classes derived with public or protected access from the class that
>   originally declared these members.
> - Direct privately derived classes that also have private access to
>   protected members.